# Spring Security 6 .permitAll() not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I'm bulding an API using Java 21, Spring boot 3 and spring security 6 authenticating in keycloak 22.

I have this code that configure my spring security:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler csrfRequestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
    csrfRequestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");

    return http
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf
                    .csrfTokenRequestHandler(csrfRequestHandler)
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                    .requestMatchers("auth/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                    .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(grantedAuthoritiesExtractor())))

            .build();
}
```

I also have this configuration pointing to my Keycloak to validate the token.
`security: oauth2: resourceserver: jwt: issuer-uri: 'http://localhost:8080/realms/core-creare'`

I'm trying to bypass authentication in the path "/auth", but the .permitAll() its not working. When I do a post request in "/auth", return as 401 unauthorized.

Comment: instead of `.requestMatchers("auth/**").permitAll()` write `.requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()`. You forgot to add `/` before `auth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem! In my security filter chain I needed to ignore the /auth in CSRF config:

```java
return http
       .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
       .csrf(csrf -> csrf
            .csrfTokenRequestHandler(csrfRequestHandler)
            .ignoringRequestMatchers("/auth/**")
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
       .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/**")).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
       .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
            .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(grantedAuthoritiesExtractor())))
       .build();
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to keep sessions? OAuth2 resource servers are usually configured as stateless, which removes the need for CSRF protection (you could completely disable CSRF protection in this filter-chain).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the Controller?
There may be a chance you didn't add the RequestMapping to the URL in RequestMatchers:

Maybe  `"api/v1/auth/**"`

insted of `"auth/**"`

Depending of your RequestMapping

Comment: Hey lptrk, thanks for you answer! I already tested this but does'nt works. In my auth controller I only have a post mapping on /auth.